# How to extract one value from an xml url using xml.etree

Tags: python, xml, django, xml-parsing, xml.etree

Im trying to print the value of just one field of a XML tree, here is the XML tree (e.g), the one that i get when i request it

```
<puco>
    <resultado>OK</resultado>
    <coberturaSocial>O.S.P. TIERRA DEL FUEGO(IPAUSS)</coberturaSocial>
    <denominacion>DAMIAN GUTIERREZ DEL RIO</denominacion>
    <nrodoc>32443324</nrodoc>
    <rnos>924001</rnos>
    <tipodoc>DNI</tipodoc>
</puco>
```

Now, i just want to print "coberturaSocial" value, here the request that i have in my views.py:

```
def get(request):
    r = requests.get('https://sisa.msal.gov.ar/sisa/services/rest/puco/38785898')
    dom = r.content
    asd = etree.fromstring(dom)
```

If i print "asd" i get this error: The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
and also in the console i get this 
I just want to print coberturaSocial, please help, new in xml parsing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract the contents of the tag and then return it wrapped in a response, like so:

```
return HttpResponse(asd.find('coberturaSocial').text)
```

Comment: thanks! actually im not very familiarized with xml and django, i could get it Alex ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `etree` is `import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree`

You can use:

```
text = r.content
dom = etree.fromstring(text)
el = dom.find('coberturaSocial')
el.text # this is where the string is
```

Comment: where exactly did you get this error? the current code doesn't return/print anything. What did you add?

Comment: i had a print there, now i delete it... it wasnt that error